# Is there a way to render a node with view mode via token?

Tags: 8, entities, tokens

Is there a way to render a node with view mode via token? Like:

```
[node:5:teaser]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the API which can get the output from the token string? I guess you are looking for [Token::replace](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/function/Token%3A%3Areplace/8.2.x)

Comment: @JimmyKo na I wanted to know if there was an existing text filter for that token, like insert view and insert block

Comment: Did you try [token_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the question is how to insert *something like* `[node:5:teaser]` into a formatted text area and get the teaser view of node 5.

This can be done with a combination of modules:

### [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) (D7,D8)

> Token Filter is a very simple module to make token values available as an input filter.

So (after adding that filter to the text format), **for the current node**, we can use e.g. [node:title] in formatted text.

### [Token Entity Render](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_entity_render) (D7, [D8 Issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_entity_render/issues/3016181))

> Provides tokens ([entity_type:render:view_mode_name]) that render full entities using view mode specified.

### [Advanced Entity Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/aet) (D7, [D8 Issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/aet/issues/2597053))

> Through AET you can query the DB for entities using Tokens.
>   Examples: [aet:node:1]

### Putting it together

In the end you should be able to use `[aet:node:5:render:teaser]` in your formatted text.

Comment: I'm amazed this is possible with tokens too, but I'd also suggest to consider the [Entity Embed module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed) for a use case like this. I'm using it successfully for media entities.

Comment: entity_embed - good point. Isn't most of this in media core these days anyway?

Comment: Advanced Entity Tokens seems like a good idea for textual data, say if I want a specific Term ID for a link [based on its UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/aet/issues/2038423).  I'll see if I can get a proper D8 version rolling based on the existing patch.